# How I can integrate $\int_0^{a} x e^{-\frac{b^2 x^2}{2 c}} J_0(n x) dx$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

How can I get a solution to the integral given below ?

$\quad \quad  \int_0^{a} x e^{-\frac{b^2 x^2}{2 c}} J_0(n x) dx$

where $a,\,b,\,c$ and $n$ are constants and $J_0$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) of order zero.

I tried the following, but got no answer in output!

```
Integrate[x*Exp[(-b^2*x^2)/(2*c)]*BesselJ[0, n*x], {x, 0, a}]
```

How I can solve for a general symbolic answer?

Comment: Are you sure there is a closed-form formula for the answer?

Comment: Since it can't do this Integrate[Exp[-x^2]*BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 1}] it probably can't do your problem without some outside expert help. BUT it can do your problem if a==Infinity along with a couple of other conditions that it will tell you when you try that.

Comment: Your integral can certainly be expanded in terms of incomplete gamma functions, but I'm not too sure it has a closed form.

Comment: The integral can alternatively be expressed by Sum[f[k] BesselJ[k, a n/Sqrt[2]], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}], with certain coefficients f[k].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it's too long...

This isn't really a *Mathematica* solution, but here's some insight into the integral.

I assume all parameters are positive. Call your integral $I$ and let $s = b^2/(2c)$. Substituting $t = \sqrt{x}$ transforms $I$ into the Laplace transform

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{L}_t\left( J_0(n \sqrt{t} \,) \theta(a^2 - t) \right)(s).$$

Now on [page 265 of Oleg Marichev's book on Laplace transforms](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFLfaa-_4OwC&pg=PA286), there are two identities for this transform. They show

$$I = \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{-a^2 s}}{s}\left( U_1(-2ia^2s, na) + iU_2(-2ia^2s, na) \right)$$

and

$$I = \frac{a^2}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-a^2 s)^k}{(k+1)!}L_k\left( -\frac{n^2}{4s} \right),$$

where $U_\nu(w, x)$ is the Lommel $U$ function, and $L_k(x)$ is the $k$th Laguerre polynomial.

Now the second identity is an infinite sum, so most wouldn't consider this a closed form.

For the first identity, the Lommel $U$ function seems to be so obscure; not only does it not exist in *Mathematica*, I couldn't even find it on Google. [**Edit** [Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=5e5JAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA170) *some* info.] Its definition is as follows:

$$ U_\nu(w, x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{w}{x}\right)^{2k + \nu} J_{2k + \nu}(x). $$

So given the obscurity of this function, and the "grossness" of its definition, I personally don't consider this a closed form either.

So with that I believe there's probably no closed form in terms of "simple enough" functions, or at least no one knows of one.

Comment: Ah, Laguerre; that one could actually be useful numerically; sometimes those series have quicker convergence than Taylor series.

Answer (score 3):

Sum of this two function is.
$$e^{-\frac{b^2 x^2}{2 c}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{b^2}{2
   c}\right)^n (-1)^n x^{2 n}}{n!}$$ and $$J_d(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n \left(\frac{t x}{2}\right)^{2 n+d}}{n!
   \Gamma (n+1+d)}$$
Multiply Sum of this functions:

```
 Iloczyn = 
 Sum[((-1)^k*(1/2*t*x)^(2 k + d)*x)/(
 k!*Gamma[k + 1 + d])*((b^2/(2 c))^(n - k)*(-1)^(n - k)*x^(
 2 (n - k)))/(n - k)!, {k, 0, n}]
```

Integrate of this functions:

```
 calka = Integrate[Iloczyn, {x, 0, a}, 
 Assumptions -> {n, a, b, c, t} \[Element] Reals, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

And we have a solution:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{a^{2 n+2} \left(-b^2\right)^n
   \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^n 2^{-d-n} (a t)^d \,
   _1\tilde{F}_1\left(-n;d+1;-\frac{c t^2}{2 b^2}\right)}{(d+2 n+2) \Gamma (n+1)}$$

$_1\tilde{F}_1$ is the regularized confluent hypergeometric function.

Check Solution.In this case d=0 because Bessel is of order zero,And Yours "n" is my "t".

```
  NIntegrate[
  x*Exp[-(b^2/(2 c))*x^2]*BesselJ[d, t*x], {x, 0, a}] /. {a -> 0.5, 
  b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 0, t -> 1} // Quiet
```

> 0.111676

```
  Sum[calka, {n, 0, 100}] /. {a -> 0.5, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 0, 
  t -> 1} // N
```

> 0.111676

The result is the same :)

**Edited**

Took into account **Guess who it is** suggestions and I deleted "d" from Bessel sum.
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n a^{2 n+2}
   \left(\frac{b^2}{c}\right)^n L_n\left(-\frac{c n^2}{2 b^2}\right)}{(2 n+2) n!}$$

$L_n$ is Laguerre polynomial.

Comment: This is what I was referring to in my comment. Your confluent hypergeometric function can be simplified further into an incomplete gamma function.